# Maven upload of zip and pom to Artifactory fails

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-deploy-plugin

I have maven repository in Artifactory.
I want to upload pom file and zip file (package from a source code) using the maven deploy command. I don't want to do it using the curl (which works by the way), but I am trying to achieve the same thing in maven.

I have a settings.xml

```
<settings>
    <interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
    <profiles/>
    <servers>
    <server>
    <id>maven-snapshot-local</id>
    <username>svcjenkins</username>
    <password>***</password>  
    </server>
   </server></servers>
</settings>
```

I have pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fa</groupId>
    <artifactId>FIXCommon</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>fa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>FIXCommon</artifactId>
                    <version>LATEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <packaging>zip</packaging>
                    <file>fix-common.zip</file>
                    <url>https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/maven-snapshot-local</url>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>`
```

I run command:
`mvn -U -X clean install deploy:deploy-file`

And the error is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata fa:FIXCommon:LATEST-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata fa:FIXCommon:LATEST-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote-repository (https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/maven-snapshot-local): authentication failed for https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/maven-snapshot-local/fa/FIXCommon/LATEST-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, status: 401 Unauthorized`
```

when I try the same with curl it passes:
`curl -u user:pass fix-common.zip https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/maven-snapshot-  local/fa/FIXCommon/LATEST-SNAPSHOT/fix-common.zip`

Can you please take a look on my XML definitions and tell me if I have missed anything?

Comment: Keep in meeting me that Maven caches error like 401 Unauthorized. So if it first reads the existing pom and somehow caches the error changing setting.xml may not have an effect. My usual approach is deleting he artifact related data in your local Maven repo (in your user home dir on the same computer `~/.m2/repository`)

Comment: I deleted the artifact, did completely the new instance run and the error is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to include **repositoryId** fields in pom definition as well.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-snapshot-local</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/maven-snapshot-local</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            ............
            <configuration>
                <repositoryId>maven-snapshot-local</repositoryId>
```